# Unity Vuforia camera movement

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am working on an augmented reality project. When the image target found, ARCamera tracks target. I want the camera just move xz-axis without affecting y-axis.

Comment: 'close' ? do you mean lock y-axis and movement only affect xz-axis ?

Comment: please help us to help you, you can show us your camera script so everyone here get idea how to help. anyway kindly check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and welcome to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the LateUpdate function to override the transform position or the ARCamera